# How do I display buffers in emacs without any keystroke?

Tags: emacs

Usually I work with multiple files. SO, I don't want to remember which files I opened and also I find it painful to hit a key to list what all files I opened. So, is there any way in emacs/spacemacs which shows me opened files in status bar all the time?

Comment: In my Emacs `C-x C-b` lists over 600 buffers... How would you fit these on screen?

Comment: Who works with 600 files at once? Do you? If yes, then you are god! THink of a case where we work on 5-6 files at once.

Comment: @username_4567, it's not uncommon for people to have Emacs sessions whose `M-x emacs-uptime` is virtually equal to their machine's uptime. If your editor is running for days / weeks / months it's not hard to get to 600 buffers. Plus, Emacs often creates buffers itself that you might not want to have listed.

Comment: @username_4567, I don't use it, but check out [`tabbar.el`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode). Something like speedbar might also help.

Comment: @username_4567: Emacs uptime here is over two weeks, and I almost never close buffers, only open new. As for managing all this stuff, I use [ido](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings). And I also have rebound `C-x C-c` to `ido-switch-buffer`. It's a waste to use such an easy shortcut for closing Emacs if you need that once a month (and `Alt+F4` works too anyway).

Comment: @Chris: I would say your comment would make a good answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**`C-x C-b`** (command `list-buffers`). And leave that buffer list open in a separate frame. It will always show you the available buffers (normal buffers that you are interested in, anyway).

Depending on your Emacs, you might need to load library `buff-menu` first. Put this in your init file: `(require 'buff-menu)`. You can also call `list-buffers` from your init file. And you can put it in its own, special frame by customizing `special-display-buffer-names` (or `display-buffer-alist`, if you are a masochist).

(There is also the output of command `ibuffer`, but it sounds like `list-buffers` is what you are really after.)